# Recover many files using ntfsundelete

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, ntfs

I am using the following command to scan for deleted files:

`sudo ntfsundelete /dev/sda1 -S 400m-20g -p 100`

How can I restore the all of the results?

I have tried:

```
sudo ntfsundelete /dev/sda1 -u 400m-20g -p 100 -d /mnt/bigboy/ntfs
```

returns `You must specify exactly one device.`

and also:

```
sudo ntfsundelete /dev/sda1 -u -i 44-6057 -p 100 -d /mnt/bigboy/ntfs
```

which seems to only recover the first file, and then outputs:

```
Couldn't create output file: File exists
```

I believe the latter is caused by the fact that for some reason I have lost all of the file nanes. (The drive was shut down immediately, so not sure how.)

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with this myself for a while.

You have to use the `-m` option, which allows you to specify a pattern for files to work on. Enclose the pattern in quotes if you want `*`, `*.jpg` or `*.*` etc to work (or else your shell will do the matching in the current directory instead of passing the pattern to ntfs-undelete).

To sum it up, what worked for me was the following command:

```
sudo ntfsundelete /dev/sdb2 -u -m '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

you only need to know how bash expansion and substitution works hence you will pass the correct arguments to ntfsundelete.

its important that you understand how does bash work when it comes to parameters and wildcards. otherwise youll be continuously misusing many console programs.